# Why are my tests telling me "param is missing or the value is empty:"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, factory-bot, rspec-rails

Using Rails 4.2, rspec 2.14, rspec-rails 2.14, faker and factory-girls-rails gems

I have a model called Appointment that I'm running some tests on and everything passes except for the #create under the controller spec.

The error message I get is:

> Failure/Error: post :create, FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:appointment)
>        ActionController::ParameterMissing:
>          param is missing or the value is empty: appointment

The Appointment model validates the presence of an association to an object called Service.

Here is my factory for appointment.rb:

```
require 'faker'

FactoryGirl.define do 
    factory :appointment do |f|
        f.service {FactoryGirl.create(:service)} 
        f.appointment_time { Faker::Time.between(DateTime.now - 1, DateTime.now) }
    end
end
```

Here is my appointment_spec.rb:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Appointment do

    it "has a valid factory" do
        FactoryGirl.create(:appointment).should be_valid
    end

    it "is invalid if it does not have a Service association" do
        FactoryGirl.build(
            :appointment, service: nil).should_not be_valid
    end

end
```

I've been following the instructions listed [here](http://everydayrails.com/2012/04/07/testing-series-rspec-controllers.html) for making my Controller Spec. I've also found a lot of stackoverflow posts that say to do the same thing, yet I still get the same error.

Here are the tests not passing from my appointment_controller_spec.rb

```
describe AppointmentsController do

 #other controller action code...

    describe "POST #create" do
        context "with valid attributes" do
            it "saves the new appointment in the database" do
                expect {
                    post :create, FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:appointment)
                }.to change(Appointment, :count).by(1)
            end

            it "redirects to show page" do
                post :create, FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:appointment)
                response.should redirect_to Appointment.last
            end
        end
end
```

I'm at a loss and hoping some one can offer some insight.

**EDIT:**

As some of you had recommended, I changed the controller spec. This is actually what I had before I changed my code to what you see above:

```
    it "saves the new appointment in the database" do
        expect {
            post :create, appointment:  FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:appointment)
        }.to change(Appointment, :count).by(1)
    end
```

The reason I changed this is because when I had this my original error message was:

> Failure/Error: expect {
>          count should have been changed by 1, but was changed by 0

Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you just need your AppointmentsController spec to read as follows:

```
 describe AppointmentsController do

 #other controller action code...

    describe "POST #create" do
        context "with valid attributes" do
            it "saves the new appointment in the database" do
                expect {
                    post :create, appointment:  FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:appointment)
                }.to change(Appointment, :count).by(1)
            end

            it "redirects to show page" do
                post :create, appointment: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:appointment)
                response.should redirect_to Appointment.last
            end
        end
end
```

Adding `appointment:` before you supply the attributes via FactoryGirl in the `post` call.

Comment: This is actually what I had before I changed my code. When I try this I get the error message: Failure/Error: expect {
       count should have been changed by 1, but was changed by 0

Comment: In that case your appointment model might be invalid. You can check your Rspec logs (see if it rolls back when it tries to insert the appointment) or throw in some breakpoints using Pry (and binding.pry) to debug, or some 'old school' `puts` statements in your controller (`puts @appointment.valid?` and/or `puts @appointment.errors.inspect` to see what's going on with the model.

Comment: You're absolutely right. The association between Appointment and Service was one that I recently added and I hadn't update my Appointments controller.

Comment: Sweet. Glad you got them green :)!

Answer (score 1):

Are you using strong_params in your controller? It looks like you are looking for an appointment param, but you are just getting a hash of the attributes.

Try this:

```
    it "saves the new appointment in the database" do
        expect {
            post :create, appointment: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:appointment)
        }.to change(Appointment, :count).by(1)
    end
```